# How to get menu Attributes from a theme's preprocess function?

Tags: 8, theming, navigation

I am developing a theme and trying to send custom vars to a twig menu template (since it pulls data from config) and have a loop to add variables in preprocess:

```
foreach($attributes as $attribute => $values){
    
    $variables[$element . '_attributes']->SetAttribute(
        $attribute,
        $values
    );
    // Also tried:
    $variables[$element]['#attributes'][$attribute][] = $values;
}
```

This function passes data to the template $variables as confirmed by kint, but SetAttribute returns a protected class property instead of the render array, while pushing to ['#attributes'] returns the attribute keys correctly but the arrays are empty...

#### How can I render the Attribute array in a menu?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was accessing variables inside of the menu {%macro%}... to pass variables to a menu you need to pass `$variables['name']` to the menu before the macro and add a parameter to the macro, i.e.:

```
// preprocess

$variables['custom_attributes'] = array(
  'class' => ['myclass']
);
```

```
//template.html.twig

{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0, custom_attributes) }}
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level, twigvars) %}

{{dump(twigvars.class)}}
```